# Different behavior of onDestroy() method in Android

Tags: android

What is the difference between the call of onDestroy method @
1) When you rotates the screen to landscape/portrait
2) When you fully close the activity and application.(i.e. it passes through onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy())

Why i am asking this question?
Because in case 1) values of savedInstanceState are reused when activity's onCreate is called again in the process of destroying and recreating activity.
But in case 2) there are no values/saved values to be picked from previous runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases `onDestroy` is the last life cycle method to be called, so there is no much difference here in cases 1 and 2.

> values of savedInstanceState are reused when activity's onCreate is called again in the process of destroying and recreating activity.

this is managed by system and not by `onDestroy`. In case of config change like screen rotation, system calls yours `onSaveInstanceState` to let you save some data, to be used in `onCreate`

> But in case 2) there are no values/saved values to be picked from previous runs.

because they are not needed - user closed your activity and next time he/she starts it - it should be started from the begining. I assume activity was finished here and `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)` was not called.

Comment: Yes, i checked and onSaveInstanceState is not called in case 2)